# Uploaded file integrity check with Azure Datalake Gen1

Tags: md5, azure-data-lake, data-integrity

WE are uploading a lot of files to Azure Datalake Gen1.
and one question came up that how do we check if the file is not corrupted or hampered during upload.

how do i check the file i uploaded is the same file that has been added into datalake?

are there any libraries to do this integrity chek?
or is ADLUploader provides any thing for this?

is there any other way to achieve the same thing?